# Php, share SESSION between requests, forcing session_id

Tags: php, session

My goal is to share session between requests, I meant every request could reach a data. First I was thinking that simply sharing via filesystem could be good, but I find out this by myself:

```
session_id('0');
session_start();
echo session_id();
var_dump ($_SESSION);
if (!isset($_SESSION['x']))
{
    $_SESSION['x'] = 0;
}
$_SESSION['x']++;
var_dump ($_SESSION);
```

this way I can see the same from browsers. My question is, is it a good practice?

EDIT: here is the full working version:

```
$m = microtime(true);
session_start();
if (session_id() == '0') // this happens when somehow our session id sticks, it should not happen ever, but if so, lets erase it
{
    setcookie (session_name(), '', time() - 3600);
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
    echo 'reload'; die;
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['x']))
{
    $_SESSION['x'] = 0;
}
$_SESSION['x']++;
$saveId = session_id();
session_write_close();

// switch to common storage
session_id('0');
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['common']))
{
    $_SESSION['common'] = 0;
}
$_SESSION['common']++;
session_write_close();

// back to our own session
session_id($saveId);
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['x'].'<br>'.(microtime(true) - $m); die;
```

I dont thing its very time consuming.

Comment: You mean all requests from whoever to use the same `SESSION`?  Probably not a good idea as this would mean you could no longer use `SESSION` for anything else (storing individual user's session data, for example - what it's intended to be used for).  What's the reasoning behind choosing `SESSION`?

Comment: for example, site must do some "cleanings" when all the other requests are hold up. I simply couldve put a file and if it exists, requests dies, but it requires is_file() everytime, which is slow. And what if two requests writes that file at the same time?

Comment: @RobBaillie, every requests may have their own session, requests just switch to the "common storage", check something, and change back to their own session

Comment: Sorry, I'm not 100% on what you mean by **site must do some "cleanings" when all the other requests are hold up.**.  Bear in mind that normal behaviour for a PHP session is to store the data in a file anyway, and that access to that session is serial (I.E. only one PHP process can access it at a time, meaning your requests will queue between `start` and `end`)

Comment: What is the "something" that is being checked?

Comment: @RobBaillie then I say something easier: to store some common data which every request may reach. And I dont want to store in database (not to load database-server), nor in filesystem (is_file and file_get_contents is slow)

Comment: Sorry to keep pushing this, but what kind of common data?

Comment: Opening a session will open and lock the session file, which is more expensive operation than just calling `is_file()` (I would suggest to use `file_exists()`). Beside, as opening a session locks the file, you create a bottleneck.

Comment: yea but its done "inside" php, while doing it manually (is_file_, file_get_contents, file_put_contents) I may cause "thread-concurrency" or how to say that. Its not "thread-safe"

Comment: Test the performance - I'm not sure it'll be much quicker than manually doing it - though you're right -if you're writing data you'll need to deal with concurrency yourself - check out my answer...

Comment: @RobBaillie yea right, Im going to test it

Comment: thx all the answers, I think its better to use "SQLite" instead of raping the session.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky to know if `SESSION` is the right place to put this data, but it's worthwhile bearing some things in mind.

- `SESSION` is designed to store data related to an individual user's visit to your site (normally being distinguished the combination of machine and browser, thanks to the session id being stored in a client side cookie).
- Default behaviour of the PHP session handler is to:

  - Store the data in a file on the server.
  - Block concurrent access to that file.
- It is *possible* to have multiple sessions for a given request, but that means ensuring you start and end each session and ensure that you keep track of the session IDs - I'm not entirely sure how you would do this without manually writing data into the client's cookie.

All in all you'll probably find that your performance using the session will be slower that just checking the existence of the file anyway (which is simpler than using the session, in terms of work done by PHP).

That said, if you're *writing* to that file then you're just going to have concurrency issues that you'll have to solve in much the same way as php sessions do anyway.

I'd say, if you're writing data, then look to your DB.  It's what they're designed for.

If you don't want to write to your primary DB and have good reason for that, then maybe consider something like a memcache DB, or some other secondary storage.

Comment: yea I know memcache, its not always supported